# Tool to draw DataModel from dump of a database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, data-modeling

I have "open source site" downloaded with its source and it uses Postgres as the database. It consists of more than 100 tables, installed and played with it. Noticed, there are many tables referred on adding the data in a form  and then I have taken a database dump of the Postgres DB.

I would like to know the references between tables using diagrams, also looking for tool to generate entity relationship model from the dump in linux environment.

If any body else aware about this please share your views,

please let me know the reason for down vote if so?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that doesn't cost $ or are you open to spending some amount of $ to do this?

Comment: @JustBob Thanks for response :) Yeah should be an open source :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free, but still in alpha stage option http://pgdesigner.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

Comment: Thanks fro the response will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the free ER modelling tools are *really* good.

You might want to try [Power*Architect](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/). To get an initial model it should be good enough, but it doesn't really know much about DBMS specific data types and things like that. But after all it's free.

If you want a really good tool, I can recommend [DbSchema](http://www.dbschema.com/). It does cost a little bit but then compared to what it offers it isn't really expensive.

Both tools are Java based and should run on Linux.